# Postfix Thinks VSFTPd is... Postfix?

Tags: postfix, ftp

```
[root@dc ~]# service postfix status 
master (pid  1616) is running...

[root@dc ~]# ps -FHww -p 1616
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1616     1  0  1794   684   0 20:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

So, any theories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely caused by a stale pid file. The specifics will vary by distribution.

Comment: Varies with the application as well, on Linux for Postfix they are likely in `/var/spool/postfix/pid`

Comment: I would kill the services and restart them, then see again, whether the PIDs match

Comment: Of course!  In hind sight, I'm kind of an idiot for not thinking of that initially...  Well, heck, what did you expect from me at midnight?  ;)